# How I can accelerate a custom rendering in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, gdi+

I work on WinForms application in which need to implement a spell check.

To redraw the form I'm using Windows message.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes Windows messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg">
    /// A Windows Message object.
    /// </param>
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.Msg)
        {
            case WM_PAINT:
                Invalidate();
                base.WndProc(ref msg);

                if (IsSpellingAutoEnabled)
                {
                    CustomPaint();
                }

                break;

        ...

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref msg);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Method CustomPaint() looks like this:

```
private void CustomPaint()
    {
        Bitmap tempBitmap;
        Graphics bufferGraphics;

        tempBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        bufferGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);
        bufferGraphics.Clip = new Region(ClientRectangle);

        _textBoxGraphics = CreateGraphics();
        bufferGraphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        foreach (var wordStartIndex in UnderlinedSections.Keys)
        {
            UnderlineWords(wordStartIndex, bufferGraphics);
        }

        _textBoxGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(tempBitmap, 0, 0);
    }
```

In UnderlineWords () lines are drawn using this code:

```
private void DrawWave(Graphics bufferGraphics, Point startOfLine, Point endOfLine)
    {
        startOfLine.Y--;
        endOfLine.Y--;

        // kvv: Определяем цвет линий подчеркивания.
        var pen = Pens.Red;

        if ((endOfLine.X - startOfLine.X) >= 4)
        {
            var points = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = startOfLine.X; i <= (endOfLine.X - 2); i += 4)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(i, startOfLine.Y));
                points.Add(new Point(i + 2, startOfLine.Y + 2));
            }

            var p = (Point[])points.ToArray(typeof(Point));
            bufferGraphics.DrawLines(pen, p);
        }
    }
```

When working with text over 500 characters application hangs. How can I solve this?

Comment: If I remove the Invalidate() call, the lines will be redrawn not correctly

Comment: Switch to using Direct2D and using glyphs for your characters.

Comment: Thank you, but Direct2D can`t be used under Windows XP, so this solution is not appropriate.

Comment: Why don't you make a normal control with `ControlStyles.UserPaint` to draw text and underlines at the same time? Your form can't emphasis everything anyway (you have to supply that `UnderlinedSections`).

Comment: ControlStyles.UserPaint not available in .NET versions below 4.5

Comment: Everything about this code looks slow; the title says accelerate; but when we get to the punchline you say it hangs. Which is it, slow or hang? [Please do not answer in comments: edit your answer with additional clarifications.]

Comment: You need to understand what `Invalidate()` does, and why you should not ever call it from without your `WM_PAINT` handler. You're also failing to call `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`. Also consider reading about the other overloads of [`Control.Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx).

Comment: Just curious why you're even working with `WM_PAINT` in a Windows Forms application. Is there some reason you can't do your work in the control's `Paint` event?

Comment: Because the UserControl is not called his handler Onpaint, when component placed on the form